# How to connect to WiFi on Ubuntu VM VirtualBox?

Tags: networking, wireless, virtualbox

I am trying to set up the WiFi connection for Ubuntu which is installed on the VirtualBox but I don't know how to do so.

On the VM VirtualBox Manager's setting --> Network tab, I enabled the Network Adapter and selected to be attached to NAT and checked off Cable Connected. It didn't work out.

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Can be more specific with your current network setup? Are you actually trying to add a WiFi connection on your VM, or just attach to the WiFi connection on the host?